# Javascript - I can't concatenate at the beginning of my string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

Here's what I want to do:

Check if there is the first character "@" within my string,
If not, add it.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#twitter").blur(function() {
            var s = $("#twitter").val();
            alert(s);
            var isAt = s.charAt(0);
            alert(isAt);
            if(isAt !== "@") {
                alert("lol");
                s = "@" + s;
            }
        });
});
```

The Problem:

When I tab to the next input (in turn blurring #twitter) Its lol'ing but not setting the value of the input to "@Rick" when I type "Rick".

Any ideas why?

Comment: Your not doing anything with `s`, the function just ends. What are you expecting to happen here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
s = "@" + s;
```

to this:

```
$("#twitter").val('@' + s);
```

The problem is that you're updating the value stored in your `s` reference, but there's no dynamic binding between that variable and the input field itself (i.e., you have to still update the `#twitter` value manually).

---

Edit: as suggested by @epascarello below, this is probably a cleaner solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#twitter').blur(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        if (val.charAt(0) !== '@') {
            $this.val('@' + val);
        }
    });
});
```

---

And... just for the heck of it, another approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#twitter').blur(function() {
        if (this.value.charAt(0) === '@') return;
        $(this).val(function(i, v) { return '@' + v });
    });
});
```

---

One more...

```
$(document).on('blur', '#twitter', function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/(@)?(.*)/, '@$2')
    });
});
```

**Note: you should probably use the first or second one... i'm getting esoteric over here...**

Comment: better as `this.value = '@' + s;` or `$(this).val('@' + s)`

Comment: @jmar777 What exactly does setting `val` to a function do?

Comment: @asawyer `$().val(function(index, value))` allows you to provide a "setter" function that is passed an index (which is useful if you're operating on multiple elements) as well as the current value.  The return value of the function becomes the new value for the element.  Basically, it's a convenient syntax for updating something's value when you need to take the current value into consideration.  There's more info in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value).

Comment: @jmar777 Thank you so much, that's really useful and I never knew it about it.

Comment: @asawyer No problem! Most all the setter methods in jQuery provide a similar syntax now (as of 1.4), so it's worth checking the docs to see if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#twitter").blur(function() {
        var s = $("#twitter").val();
        alert(s);
        var isAt = s.charAt(0);
        alert(isAt);
        if(isAt !== "@") {
            alert("lol");
            $("#twitter").val("@" + s);
        }
    });
});
```